# How to get text to not scroll in a terminal

Tags: c++, coding-style

I am trying to write a C++ program where the screen updates every 1 second.  However, I want the screen to be similar to htop, where it updates and does not have to scroll with each update.  That way, I don't have a step-by-step iteration in my terminal.

Does anyone know what this style is called or how to program it?

Thanks!

Comment: Jerry and jonsca has given you the correct answer. If you want to roll your own its a pain the ... Basically you need to look up terminal codes or attempt to write directly to the text memory (doubt it works on any modern operating system).

Answer (score 5):

The usual way is with something like `ncurses`. If you're on Windows, it has console functions built in so you can do the same without any extra libraries (though they do take a while to understand). If you only want one line of output, you can use a `'\r'` to return to the beginning of the current line and/or `\b` to backspace over previous characters (handy if yoy only want to overwrite a few little bits and pieces).

Answer (score 3):

You'll need a library like curses (on *nix) or pdcurses for Windows (conio functions would probably still work on windows).